# Error when trying to get an access token in xero-laravel authorization process

Tags: laravel, xero-api

i am integrating Xero to a laravel application for the first time and it has been chaotic.I am trying to use this package:https://github.com/ayles-software/xero-laravel which completes the first step of redirecting users to xero,and although response with a code is returned to my redirect url,it comes with this error **Calcinai\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Exception\XeroProviderException
Forbidden** which i think means my code cant be exchanged for an access token.I tried another package and i get an error as well when trying to exchange the code for the access token.With postman,i sometimes get an access token but mostly i get an **Authentication failed**  error when i try to get my access token even though i feel i am doing everything as expected.So i was wondering if there is something i should watch out for when using a demo account in local development environment apart from the limits?

Comment: If you are struggling to get an access token with Postman, I would try to figure out that issue before trying to get one with the packages. If you are unsuccessful with Postman it seems the error you are encountering there would be replicated with any packages you use.

Have you followed the instructions at https://developer.xero.com/documentation/tools/postman

to test your OAuth flow and getting tokens?

Comment: Sorry i took long,yes i followed the instructions,sometimes i get an access token,sometimes not